# Python to check a word and write the rest of the line into a txt file as normal lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file-io

I was just trying to segregate a log file into 3 different files. Each line starts with either 'INFO', 'DEBUG' or 'ERROR'. I want to read this first word in each line and then write them into separate files as Info.txt, Debug.txt, Error.txt. My approach was this and I'm not sure where am i going wrong.

```
def Fileparse():
key = []
with open("logfile.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line.split()
        if key[0] == 'INFO':
            #l = f.readline()
            ifile = open('Info.txt', 'w+')
            ifile.write(str(key))
            ifile.write('\n')
            key.clear()                
        elif key[0] == 'DEBUG':
            #l = f.readline()
            dfile = open('Debug.txt', 'w+')
            dfile.write(str(key))
            dfile.write('\n')
            key.clear()
        elif key[0] == 'ERROR':
            #l = f.readline()
            efile = open('Error.txt', 'w+')
            efile.write(str(key))
            efile.write('\n')
            key.clear()
        else:
            continue
    f.close()
if __name__=='__main__':
    Fileparse()
```

this is my code and the way its performing is also a bit confusing.

```
logfile.txt:

DEBUG Heloo
INFO HELLLIIIIO
INFO Hi i am perakwa
ERROR I AM error
INFO I AM AASSA
DEBUG ISADANSLK

Info.txt:
['INFO', 'I', 'AM', 'AASSA']
akwa']


Debug.txt:
['DEBUG', 'ISADANSLK']


Error.txt:
['ERROR', 'I', 'AM', 'error']
```

I'm not sure why only one line is being written on the output files. Also i want them to be written as plainly as in logfile.txt and not like "['Debug', 'Example']" but more like "Debug Example". Please help me out with this. I'm trying to google but nothing seems to help me with this.

Comment: `key` is a list because you got it from calling `line.split()`. If you want the original text, you should just write `line` to the file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is best dealt with using a control structure of some kind - in this case a dictionary.

The open mode in the original question is w+ which doesn't make a lot of sense because a new file will be created (read/write). Append mode probably makes more sense.

```
CONTROL = {'INFO': 'Info.txt', 'DEBUG': 'Debug.txt', 'ERROR': 'Error.txt'}

def Fileparse():
    with open('logfile.txt') as f:
        for line in f:
            key, *_ = line.split()
            if (txt := CONTROL.get(key)):
                with open(txt, 'a') as out:
                    out.write(line)
```

Comment: I'm a little new to Python. This worked exactly the way i wanted. May i know what is this called? So i can learn those concepts

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much simpler way of doing things.

Not sure why you are splitting the lines, key[0] etc.

I have commented out a print stmt, you can use it to understand the solution better.

Basically each line is a string, and in strings you can use the 'in' keyword to check if 'INFO'/'ERROR'/'DEBUG' is present in the line.

```
with open("log.txt", "r") as filename:
    for line in filename:
        # print("--<>",line)
        if "INFO" in line:
            with open("info.txt", "a") as infofile:
                infofile.write("%s\n" % line)
                
        if "DEBUG" in line:
            with open("debug.txt", "a") as debugfile:
                debugfile.write("%s\n" % line) 
                
        if "ERROR" in line:          
            with open("error.txt", "a") as errorfile:
                errorfile.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Comment: There's a **HUGE** difference between using *in* versus making a literal comparison against the first token in the string

Comment: Thank you all so much for helping me out. It worked well

Comment: @Vlad OP has mentioned that each line starts with 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'ERROR'. Also in the example shown there is only one occurrence of one of those words in each line. 'in' keyword gets the job done for OP's requirement.

Comment: What if a line looks like this: 'DEBUG Here is some INFO'. That would incorrectly be written to both info.txt **and** debug.txt

Comment: @Vlad neither the question nor the example provided indicates that as a possible case.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you overwrite the file's content each time since you're using `w+`. To do what you're looking for you should use `a+` in order to append the line each time like so:

```py
open('file.txt', 'a+')
```

Comment: Mode 'a' would suffice as there's no suggestion that the file needs to be read

Comment: @Vlad of course but I just modified OP's code, if I had to change it I'd make a lot of changes tbh...